# MySQL Connector / Python no realiza el Commit

Tags: python, mysql

Tengo la siguiente función que debe tomar los datos desde un JSON y guardarlo en una base de datos MySQL

```
def saveMetric(metrics):
    cnx     = RDS_Connect()
    cursor  = cnx.cursor()
    jsonMetrics = json.loads(metrics)
    #print type(jsonMetrics['Metrics'])
    # Every 2000 registries, the script will start overrriding values
    persistance = 2000
    save_metrics_query = (
            "REPLACE INTO metrics "
            "SET metric_seq = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(row_id), 0) %% %(persistance)d + 1 FROM metrics AS m), "
            "instance_id = \'%(instance_id)s\', "
            "service = \'%(service)s\' , "
            "metric_name = \'%(metric_name)s\', "
            "metric_value = %(metric_value)f"
           )
    for metric in jsonMetrics['Metrics']:
        formatData = {}
        formatData['persistance'] = persistance
        formatData['instance_id'] = arguments.dimensionValue
        formatData['service'] = jsonMetrics['Service']
        formatData['metric_name'] = metric
        formatData['metric_value'] = jsonMetrics['Metrics'][metric]

        print save_metrics_query % formatData

        try:
            cursor.execute(save_metrics_query, formatData, multi=True)
            logger('info','Metrics were saved successfully!')
            cnx.commit()
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            logger('error', "Something went wrong: %s" % err)
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

`RDS_Connect()` realiza la conexión a una instancia de RDS, esa función ya la probé y funciona correctamente. La cuestión es que después de ejecutar esta función, los datos no aparecen en la DB. Probé ejecutando la query a mano 3 veces y funciona. Aquí se ve el resultado de esas 3 ejecuciones.

Creo que podría haber un problema con el `commit()` pero no lo estaría encontrando.

Si sirve de ayuda, el JSON que alimenta la función es así:

```
{
  "Metrics": {
      "CPUUtilization": 1.33, 
      "NetworkIn": 46428.0, 
      "NetworkOut": 38772.0
  }, 
  "Id": "i-03932937bd67622c4", 
  "Service": "AWS/EC2"
}
```

Si alguien ve lo que está sucediendo, agradecería la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diría que pasas mal los argumentos del query. Los *paramstyles* de la DB-API de python **no emplean comillas**, no equivalen a los argumentos de las cadenas de formato. En concreto, el fomato `pyformat` es siempre `%(name)s`, sin comillas y con la `s` de *string*.

Prueba así a ver:

```
save_metrics_query = (
        "REPLACE INTO metrics "
        "SET metric_seq = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(row_id), 0) %% %(persistance)s + 1 FROM metrics AS m), "
        "instance_id = %(instance_id)s, "
        "service = %(service)s , "
        "metric_name = %(metric_name)s, "
        "metric_value = %(metric_value)s"
       )
```

Comment: Aunque esto no era la causa del problema, es un muy buen tip. Lo voy a tener en cuenta. Gracias!

Comment: No entiendo bien. Has dado por buena la solución de @César de no reutilizar el cursor, pero en los comentarios das a entender que el problema era que ponías mal el formato de los parámetros.

Comment: Es verdad. Me confundí con otro comment de otro thread. Ahora trato de corregirlo.

Answer (score 1):

Podría ser el tema de la reutilización de los cursores, yo tuve alguna vez problemas con eso, deberías estar usando un cursor por transacción en vez de usar el mismo cursor para todas las transacciones.

Habiendo dicho esto, valdría la pena que intentes actualizar tu código para que quede más o menos así:

```
def saveMetric(metrics):
    cnx = RDS_Connect()    
    # Lo que resta de tu código
    for metric in jsonMetrics['Metrics']: 
        cursor  = cnx.cursor()
        # Tus operaciones
        cursor.close()
    cnx.close()
```

Comment: Justamente esto creo que causo el problema. Pero no salto ninguna exception. El tema estaba con esta linea.<<<<<  "metric_value = %(metric_value)f"         >>>>> esa f. Lo cambie por una s y funciono. Gracias!